# Rails 6: Routing with scope for User model/controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-6

In my rails 6 project (development mode) i've set up a User model along with devise.
In routes.rb i have:

```
scope :auth do
  devise_for :users
end

resources :users, except: :index
resources :articles, only: [:show, :update]

scope :passport do 
  resources :users, only: :index
  resources :articles, except: [:show, :update]    
end
```

Prefixes work as expected for articles but not for users.
For some reason */passport/users* refering to *users#index*
doesn't get the *users_path* prefix (GET) at all.
It's without any prefix.
Request to localhost:3000/passport/users works fine.

Is there a conflict with devise?

Im missing something but what is it?

Answer (score 0):

Problem not in device gem

You can try this

```
scope :auth do
  devise_for :users
end

scope :passport do 
  resources :users, only: :index
  resources :articles, except: [:show, :update]    
end

resources :users, except: :index
resources :articles, only: [:show, :update]
```

I don't know why, but it works

Comment: changing the order didn't solve it for me.
It actually broke other resources I have in the routes.rb as well.

Comment: I tried this again and now I always have right prefixes in any order. truly speaking I don't know what kind of magic it is.

Comment: I suspect that scope works with methods that have corresponding views (GET).
For example new, edit, index, show
I don't think it works with POST methods such as create, destroy, update, that's why they don't get paths.